# How to Query Nested XML in Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to query/output the EMPLOYEE nodes which is repeating multiple times.
My query is giving me error that it is not expecting multi-item sequence. Eventually I would need to loop the repeated EMPLOYEE data in PLSQL. But First I would like to at least be able to run the SQL to produce the desire result. I ran out of ideas.

See my query and XML below.

```
    select
    xmlt.recordid,
    xmlt.mfirstname,
    xmlt.mlastname,
    xmlt.efirstname,
    xmlt.elastname,
    FROM   
    test_xml x,
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http:testxml.com' AS "ns"), '//ns:abccomp' 
    passing            xmltype(x.xml) 
    columns
    recordid varchar2(200) path '//ns:recordid/ns:identification',
    mfirstname varchar2(200)  path '//ns:accounting/ns:manager/ns:personname/ns:firstname',
    mlastname varchar2(200)  path '//ns:accounting/ns:manager/ns:personname/ns:lastname',
    efirstname varchar2(200)  path '//ns:accounting/ns:employee/ns:personname/ns:firstname',
    elastname varchar2(200)  path '//ns:accounting/ns:employee/ns:personname/ns:lastname'
    )Xmlt;


        <ns:wrap
xmlns:ns="http:testxml.com">
<ns:body>
    <ns:abccomp>
        <ns:recordid>
            <ns:identification>955613218915</ns:identification>
        </ns:recordid>
        <ns:accounting>
            <ns:manager>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>frank</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>phillips</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:manager>
            <ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>jimmy</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>smith</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
            <ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>yuri</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>oga</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>amanda</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>hicks</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
        </ns:accounting>
    </ns:abccomp>
</ns:body>
```

</ns:wrap>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple `XMLTABLE`s:

```sql
SELECT x.recordid,
       x.mfirstname,
       x.mlastname,
       e.*
FROM   test_xml t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         xmlnamespaces('http:testxml.com' AS "ns"),
         '//ns:wrap/ns:body/ns:abccomp' 
         PASSING xmltype(t.xml) 
         COLUMNS
           recordid   varchar2(200) path '//ns:recordid/ns:identification',
           mfirstname varchar2(200) path '//ns:accounting/ns:manager/ns:personname/ns:firstname',
           mlastname  varchar2(200) path '//ns:accounting/ns:manager/ns:personname/ns:lastname',
           accounting XMLTYPE       path '//ns:accounting'
       ) x
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         xmlnamespaces('http:testxml.com' AS "ns"),
         '//ns:accounting/ns:employee' 
         PASSING x.accounting
         COLUMNS
           efirstname varchar2(200) path '//ns:personname/ns:firstname',
           elastname  varchar2(200) path '//ns:personname/ns:lastname'
       ) e;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> RECORDID     | MFIRSTNAME | MLASTNAME | EFIRSTNAME | ELASTNAME
> :----------- | :--------- | :-------- | :--------- | :--------
> 955613218915 | frank      | phillips  | jimmy      | smith    
> 955613218915 | frank      | phillips  | yuri       | oga      
> 955613218915 | frank      | phillips  | amanda     | hicks
> ```

For your test data (which was missing an opening `<ns:employee>` and a closing `</ns:wrap>` tag):

```sql
INSERT INTO test_xml ( xml ) VALUES ( '<ns:wrap xmlns:ns="http:testxml.com">
<ns:body>
    <ns:abccomp>
        <ns:recordid>
            <ns:identification>955613218915</ns:identification>
        </ns:recordid>
        <ns:accounting>
            <ns:manager>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>frank</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>phillips</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:manager>
            <ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>jimmy</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>smith</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
            <ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>yuri</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>oga</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
            <ns:employee>
                <ns:personname>
                    <ns:firstname>amanda</ns:firstname>
                    <ns:lastname>hicks</ns:lastname>
                </ns:personname>
            </ns:employee>
        </ns:accounting>
    </ns:abccomp>
</ns:body>
</ns:wrap>' );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02d2c3481613a9b0d84f72c3e820040a)*